# Analytic curve divides disk into two Jordan regions

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $\gamma:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic Jordan arc. It seems natural to me that for every $\gamma(t_0)$ we can find a disk with center $\gamma(t_0)$ that is divided by $\gamma$ into two Jordan regions, but I can't prove it. In fact, I think that even if $\gamma$ is a $C^1$ Jordan arc, then the above also holds. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean for the domain of $\gamma$ to be a closed interval? The usual definition of Jordan Arc seems to assume that.

Comment: @JohnHughes No I mean that it is defined on the open interval and is injective

Answer (score 2):

For an open-interval domain, i believe the answer is "no." [image: see crude drawing below] The gist is this:

Take the graph of $x \mapsto \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $0 < x < 1$. Connect the $x = 1$ end to the top of a vertical line from $(0, 1)$ to $(0, -1)$. Connect the bottom of that line to a similar sine-curve on the left side of the axis.

At the origin, every disk about the origin is divided into infinitely many slices by the image of $\gamma$.

Post-comment addition: Consider
$$
x = \frac{\cos t } {1 + \sin^2 t} \\
y = \frac{\cos t \sin t } {1 + \sin^2 t}
$$
for $\pi/2 < t < 5\pi/2$. That gives a lemniscate whose ends *almost* touch the origin. It can clearly be extended to an analytic function on a neighborhood of that interval on the real axis, hence satisfies all of Robert Israel's suggested conditions (except the the "compact interval" part, which the OP explicitly said was not what was wanted).

Comment: See picture. $$

Comment: Perhaps a reasonable assumption is that $\gamma$ is one-to-one on a compact interval, analytic on a complex neighbourhood of that interval, and you want the condition about Jordan regions to hold for $t_0$ in the interior of the interval.

Comment: Why not just a smooth figure-8 where the open ends of the curve approach the center?

Comment: @Henning: the very first thing I thought of was a lemniscate, and then saw the definition of Jordan arc included "injective", and somehow got off onto the topologist's sine-curve thing rather than deleting a point from the domain. :(

Comment: @RobertIsrael: That sounds reasonable, but I *think* that Henning's example might well satisfy all those conditions. (I've never really understood what "analytic" means except for functions from $\mathbb C$ to itself. :(  )

Comment: What if we had a curve just as @RobertIsrael said?

Comment: It sounds like @Robert is, by saying "on a compact interval", proposing to have $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$ instead of $\gamma:(0,1)\to \mathbb C$, and my example certainly doesn't satisfy that.

Comment: Right...that's why I asked about closed vs open in the initial comment section. @Antonis said he wanted "open".

Comment: I've added the explicit leminscate to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a $C^1$ counterexample, consider a path $\gamma: [-1,1] \to \mathbb C$ as follows.  For $-1 \le t \le 0$, $\gamma(t) = -t^2$.
For positive integers $n$, from $t = (n+1)^{-1/2}$ to $t=n^{-1/2}$
the path goes from in straight line segments from $1/(n+1)$ to $e^{i/(n+1)}/n$ 
to $e^{-i/(n+1)}/(n+1)$ to $1/n$.
Note that the length of these three segments is  $O(1/n^2)$, which must be traversed in time $\Theta(n^{-3/2})$.  Thus we can do this with a $C^1$ function, starting and ending the segments at speed $0$ and moving with maximum speed $O(n^{-1/2})$.
Since the maximum speed goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, $\gamma'$ will be continuous at $0$.

Note that the path intersects each circle $|z| = r$ for $0 < r < 1$ at least four times, so it cuts the disk $|z| \le r$ into more than two regions.

Here's a picture:

[image]