# Can I choose this kind of neighborhood of a point on a curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

> $\textbf{Question}$ Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^{2}$ is a continuously differentiable, 1-1 function. If $f(a)\in f([0,1])$, then should there be some open ball $B(f(a),\epsilon)$, centered at $f(a)$ with small radius $\epsilon$ so that $f([0,1])\cap B(f(a),\epsilon)=f(a-\delta_{1},a+\delta_{2})\neq f([0,1])$ for some $\delta_{1},\delta_{2}>0$?

One observation was that if $f$ is a space-filling curve, then the answer is no. But the conditions on $f$ requires it rectifiable, and also because it's 1-1 , its image should be a nowhere dense closed set. So, $f([0,a-e])\cup f([a+e,1])$ for small $e>0$ is closed and its complement is nonempty open, so there is some open ball centered at $f(a)$ that doesn't intersect with $f([0,a-\epsilon])\cup f([a+\epsilon,1])$. So there is some $B(f(a),\epsilon)$ s.t. $f([0,1])\cap B(f(a),\epsilon)\subset f(a-\delta_{1},a+\delta_{2})$ for some $\delta_{1},\delta_{2}>0$. But should $\supset$ also hold for some suitable choices?

Comment: Space-filling curves are not injective anyway. But "rectifiable" is not enough; $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &x=0 \\ x \sin(100\log x) & x>0 \end{cases} $$ is Lipschitz and thus its graph is rectifiable, but it intersects every circle around $(0,0)$ multiple times. What it fails to be is differentiable at $0$...

Comment: Of course, if you choose $\varepsilon$ _large enough_ then the ball will contain the entire curve. :-) I'm assuming you don't want to use that loophole, though.

Comment: @ Makholm: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes I wanted to keep $\epsilon$ small.

Comment: The curve described by Robert Israel [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866945/14366) appears to be a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

In the form stated the claim is false. You may consider e.g. $t\in [0,1]\mapsto (x,y)=(t^6, t^3 \sin \frac{1}{t})$. The envelope (where |sin| is one) is of the form $x=y^2$. The distance to the origin is a wildly oscillating function as $t\rightarrow 0$. You may also construct a $C^\infty$ counter-example.

It is true if we only ask that for any $\delta>0$ we have inclusion $f([0,1])\cap B(f(a),\epsilon) \subset f(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Assume the contrary and let $a\in[0,1]$ be a point where the condition fails. Then $f^{-1}B(f(a),1/n)$ does not shrink to $a$, i.e. there is $\delta>0$ and $x_n\in[0,1]$ so that $|x_n-a|\geq \delta$ and $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(a)$. Now $K=[0,1]\setminus ]a-\delta,a+\delta[$ is compact so there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}\rightarrow b\in K$ and by continuity $f(a)=f(b)$ but $a<>b$.

Comment: Your conclusion that "$f^{-1}(B(f(a),1/n)$ does not shrink to $a$" is not necessarily true for a counterexample; see [Rober't Israel's curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866945/14366) for a counterexample that does not have the property you claim.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the intersection need not be the image of an interval"? It is an explicit requirement in the question that the intersection of the curve and the ball _must be_ the image of an interval.

Comment: Right, as I say in the end the intersection need not be the image of an interval. So I am tacitly already omitting that part from the hypothesis. Should rewrite this...

Comment: But the requirement that the intersection must be the image of an interval is the _entire_ requirement on $\varepsilon$ in the question. If you're "tacitly omitting" that, then which connection to the question being asked is there left?